# Which phrase should be used, to get success or for success?

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence, which phrase should be used, 'to get success' or 'for success'?

> You should know the importance of having good friends to get success/ for success.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you found this sentence? The whole thing doesn't sound very English.

Comment: @JavaLatte - I'm guessing the O.P. is writing something and asked us to weigh in where he or she got stuck. (If so, I wish the O.P. would just come out and say so; this beating around the bush isn't very helpful, nor does it make a for a good question.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about 'networking'?

> " Business networking is an effective low-cost marketing method for
>   developing sales opportunities and contacts, based on referrals and
>   introductions - either face-to-face at meetings and gatherings, or by
>   other contact methods such as phone, email, and increasingly social
>   and business networking websites."

[LINK](http://www.businessballs.com/business-networking.htm)

Comment: I think this answer would be better if we could tell the O.P. how we'd use _networking_ in this context (e.g., _When it comes to success, you should know the importance of networking_ – or something like that).